# Google Web Authorization Broker create secret uri

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-authentication

I want to create the UserCredentials for my program and the signature of this task seems to be

```
Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
(Uri clientSecretsUri, IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken);
```

All tutorials I found only just create a ClientSecrets-class and pass that as an argument, sadly this class does not have a .ToUri() method. I also can not find any documentation on how this uri has to be constructed. So given that I obviously have my client id and secret ( and redirect uri's if needed ) how do I create the uri needed for this authorization?

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming your're developing for the universal windows platform? Then this will work:

as neosapien said, you can download the client_secrets.json from the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Add it to your project with a build action of `Content`.

then load it according to your location in the project (in this case `<ProjectDirectory>/Assets/client_secrets.json`) like so:

```
await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync( 
                    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secrets.json"),
                    new[] {CalendarService.Scope.Calendar, DriveService.Scope.Drive},
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None)
```

Comment: Great stuff, thanks! Wonder why this isn't documented very well, is there any particular source you got working solution from?

Comment: nope, I think I was reading a whole lot of googles source code to understand what it needs and then supply that.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/) and download the .json file from the Credentials item under the APIs & Auth menu in the left sidebar.

If you want to include .json file in your deployment you can just encrypt it to keep your secret key and id safe.

The following usings are needed:

- `using Google.Apis.Services // for BaseClientService`
- `using Google.Apis.Util.Store // for FileDataStore`
- `using System.Threading // for CancellationToken.None`
- `using System.Reflection // for accessing the embedded resource of the json file`
- `Using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2`
- any other google scope specific resources; e.g., Google.Apis.Calendar for the calendar scope or Google.Apis.Gmail for email access.

Create fields and properties as follows:

```
UserCredentials credentials;
CalendarService calendarService
```

and this is the code I use for interacting with the Google API:

```
try 
{
     GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "Tasks.Auth.Store";
     credentials = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          GoogleClientSecrets.Load({file name or stream}).Secrets,
          new[] {
          GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose,
          CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
          Google.Apis.Plus.v1.PlusService.Scope.UserinfoEmail },
          "user", CancellationToken.None,
          new FileDataStore("AppDataFolderName"));
} ...
```

Since I am installing the encrypted .json file as a part of my software, the entire try/catch block is inside of a `using (var cryptoStream = Encryption.ReadJson()) block followed by GoogleClientSecrets.Load(cryptoStream).Secrets` but you could just as easily use any file path and name you like.

In the above sample, I am requesting access to read and write gmail, read and write to the Google calendar, and I'd like to know who they are on G+.
Make sure you have enabled the correct APIs in the Google Developers Console.

The real magic doesn't actually happen until you use the credentials to create a service.  In the above example, you would use the following code:

```
calendarService = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
ApplicationName = "My Application"
});
```

to access the calendar.

I'm pretty sure this is an extremely hacked together way of doing this, but it works for me without any problems.  I pieced it together from a lot of the tutorials found here [Google Drive | Daimto](http://www.daimto.com/category/googledrive/)

Comment: -1 doesn't answer the question. I stumbled upon the same problem in a UWP project referencing the google apis: that version of the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker only has a AuthorizeAsync Method with a first parameter of `Uri clientSecretsUri` !